# How to escape specifying Full Name while setting up an email account with a profile?

Tags: mail.app, email, plist, apple-configurator, configuration-profiles

I am attempting to set up an email account using a configuration profile created with Apple Configurator 2. My goal is to avoid using User Display Name, so the raw source of a letter would begin with something like this:

```
From: john.doe@example.net
Content-Type: text/plain
```

and not like this:

```
From: John Doe <john.doe@example.net>
Content-Type: text/plain
```

While it is allowed to not specify a name when setting up an account manually (tested on both macOS and iOS), there is some problem when I try to do the same thing with a profile.

During the profile installation it asks to:

> ENTER YOUR FULL NAME FOR THE EMAIL ACCOUNT "JOHN.DOE@EXAMPLE.NET"

I tried to edit the profile file manually by modifying those lines:

```
<key>EmailAccountName</key>
<string></string>
```

However, the problem remains.

How can I solve this? Is there any special notation for Apple's config files which would indicate that a user wants to leave that field empty (e.g., the null character or something like that)?